# Can I alias a color?

Tags: color, alias

I would like to define some colors and then define some aliases to them.  For instance, if I define the following color:

`\definecolor{MyColorA}{rgb}{0.1,0.2,0.3}`

and then want to define an alias "NoteColor" to be the same as "MyColorA", what is the command?
I tried:

`\definecolor{NoteColor}{named}{MyColorA}`

but this did not work. Any suggestions or links welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the second command didn't work? It should have.  It's an alternate syntax to the `\colorlet` solutions given in the answers: `\definecolor{Alias}{named}{ExistingColour}` = `\colorlet{Alias}{ExistingColour}`.

Comment: I tried `\definecolor{Alias}{named}{ExistingColour}` but it still did not work.  However, the xcolor solution below works.

Comment: @kmmcoy Both commands are from `xcolor` so they should both with.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you load the `xcolor` package, which accepts the same commands of `color` package and many more, you can say

```
\colorlet{Notecolor}{MyColorA}
```

Comment: Perfect! I changed to use the `xcolor` package and used `\colorlet{Alias}{ExistingColour}` which works nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

With `xcolor` package you can use `\colorlet`.